# Build own new message from BindingResult

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I would like to consult you about the BindingResult. Take a look at my situation below.

My messages.properties store error message as follows

```
error.required=Please input {0}
```

My controller has rejected 2 fields with the same error as follows

```
bidingResult.rejectValue("field1", "error.required", new Object[]{"Field1"}, null);
bidingResult.rejectValue("field2", "error.required", new Object[]{"Filed2"}, null);
```

My view has extract messages by used Thymeleaf syntax as follows

```
<div th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('*')}" th:text="${err}"></div>
```

The result will show 2 messages as follows

```
Please input Field1
Please input Field2
```

**My question is can I create a new messages object by BindingResult to show a message like this**

```
Please input Field1 and Field2
```

I want to merge the same error together and concatenate message param

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that will be to create a custom validator at the object level. Start with a custom annotation:

```
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType; 
import java.lang.annotation.Retention; 
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.TYPE) 
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = BothFieldsPresentValidator.class) 
public @interface BothFieldsPresent {
      String message() default "{BothFieldsPresent}";
      Class<?>[] groups() default {};
      Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
  }
```

Next, create the custom validator:

```
public class BothFieldsPresentValidator implements ConstraintValidator<BothFieldsPresent, MyObject> {

  public boolean isValid(MyObject myObject, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    
    if( myObject.getField1() == null && myObject.getField2() == null ) {
      context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
      context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("{BothFieldsPresent}")
             .addConstraintViolation()
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

Add the new custom annotation to your `MyObject` class:

```
@BothFieldsPresent
public class MyObject {
  ...
}
```

In your controller, do something like this:

```
@PostMapping
public String doPost(@Valid @ModelAttribute("myObject") MyObject myObject, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
  if( bindingResult.hasErrors() ) {
    return "template-name"
  }

  service.doSomething(myObject);

  return "redirect:/somewhere"
}
```

Add this to `messages.properties`:

```
BothFieldsPresent=Please input Field1 and Field2
```

Comment: Thank you for your support, but I can’t use the custom constraintvalidator to validate form level due to my logical check logic is complex. I have reject fields on both service, common utils, custom validator. Also, actually the message parameters is dynamic.

Comment: I am sorry for my few detail. The reason why I has reject fields because in my view have check each input field has reject or not. If that input field has rejected, it will highlight by set background to red color.